# How to read every line of a text file and replace using regex?

Tags: python, regex, replace

I am trying to read a file that contains strings starting with the same pattern but ending with different numbers. I want to shorten these strings by replacing them (with regex) and write them in a different file. I was trying to use `re.sub` (I didn't want to use `split`).

Original file is like this:

```
@C00127:132:CDTL1ACXX:11000(several digits...)
@C00127:132:CDTL1ACXX:55588(several digits...)
@C00127:132:CDTL1ACXX:99999(several digits...)
```

My idea is to write a new file containing the conserved pattern of the strings (i.e., "@C00127:132:CDTL1ACXX:") followed by the **first 5** variable digits.

So I thought about a script like this:

```
import re
general_ID = open("general_ID.txt", "w+")
x = raw_input('type the name of the fastq file that you wanna extract the IDs: ')
with open (x, 'rt') as myfile:   
    for line in myfile:
        general_ID.write(re.sub('@C00127:132:CDTL1ACXX:......+', '@C00127:132:CDTL1ACXX:.....', line))
general_ID.close()
```

When I run this script, my original file from this:

```
@C00127:132:CDTL1ACXX:11000(several digits...)
@C00127:132:CDTL1ACXX:55588(several digits...)
@C00127:132:CDTL1ACXX:99999(several digits...)
etc
```

Ends up like this:

```
C00127:132:CDTL1ACXX:.....
C00127:132:CDTL1ACXX:.....
C00127:132:CDTL1ACXX:.....
etc
```

Comment: can you provide expected sample output?

Comment: Let´s say my original file contains: "@C00127:132:CDTL1ACXX:110052527274723423424" and so on. I'd like to retrieve ""@C00127:132:CDTL1ACXX:11005", i.e., the first five numbers, after the conserved string (""@C00127:132:CDTL1ACXX:", that is present in all IDs, in each line).

Comment: Please check the answers below and consider accepting the answer with the solution that worked best for you.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the regex like

```
@C00127:132:CDTL1ACXX:(\d{5})
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/R8lH7F/1/). Details:

- `@C00127:132:CDTL1ACXX:` -  literal text
- `(\d{5})` - Group 1: five digits

Python code:

```
import re, os
x = input('type the name of the fastq file that you wanna extract the IDs: ')
if os.path.isfile(x):
    with open("general_ID.txt", "w") as general_ID:
        with open (x, 'r') as myfile:   
            for line in myfile:
                m = re.search(r'@C00127:132:CDTL1ACXX:(\d{5})', line)
                if m:
                    general_ID.write( "{}\n".format(m.group(1)) )
```

Comment: Thank you for your help Wiktor. Regex is efficient in doing what I needed, but I am not sure why "general_ID.txt" is created empty.  I thought that by adding "general_ID.close()" (by the end of the code) would make it work, but it didnt. I will think this through.

Comment: @MMZ Maybe the strings are not the start of lines, I updated the solution

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks a lot. I tried the code but got an error at this line `x = raw_input` like that `NameError: name 'raw_input' is not defined`

Comment: @YasserKhalil Just use `input`. The `raw_input` function was built in Python 2. It is deprecated in version 3.

Comment: And inside should I put the text input or the file path (text file)?

Comment: @YasserKhalil `with open (x, 'r') as myfile:` requires `x` to be a valid file path. It can be just file name if the file is in the current directory.

Comment: Forgive me as I am newbie at python. I tried this line `x = input('Input.txt')` but seems not to work with me. I have created a text file in the same path of the python file and named it `Input.txt`

Comment: @YasserKhalil Try full path.

Comment: Can you please put a temp path so as to have a look where exactly should I put the path and how is the path as I tried this `x = input('C:/Users/Future/Desktop/Temp/Input.txt')` but didn't work for me?

Comment: @YasserKhalil It must be `x = r'C:\Users\Future\Desktop\Temp\Input.txt'`

Comment: I think this is OK but I didn't get any results. I have copied the text from the regex demo page and put it in the text file ..

Comment: Oops I got it. There is a generated text file with the results. Thank you very much.

Comment: @YasserKhalil Yes, just make sure you provide correct file paths.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew This was not my question. I am your follower here :)

Comment: @YasserKhalil Sorry, I am really tired now :)

Answer (score 0):

#### Use a slice

Regular expressions are not needed to solve this problem. The prefix has a fixed length; just take a fixed length slice of each line.

```
id_len = 5
prefix_len = len("C00127:132:CDTL1ACXX:")
keep_len = prefix_len + id_len

with open("general_ID.txt", "w+") as general_ID:
    x = raw_input('type the name of the fastq file that you wanna extract the IDs: ')

    with open (x, 'rt') as myfile:   
        for line in myfile:
            general_ID.write("{}\n".format(line[:keeplen]))
```

A useful tool might accept the length of each line to write out. Or maybe look at the first few lines to determine the length of the common prefix automatically.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I modified the last line as:   general_ID.write (f"{line[:37]}\n")  because the length of what I want to retrieve is fixed. But python is accusing the last quotation mark as an invalid syntax. Any thoughts on that? Thanks.

Comment: I just realized you are using Python 2 (Python 3 doesn't have `raw_input`). I don't think Python 2 has f-strings.  I changed the last line to `{}\n".format(line[:keeplen])`